# JavaScript validation for invalid file type

Tags: javascript, file

I have a scenario wherein user is trying to view an invalid image file (for example an .dll file renamed to JPG extenstion). How do I alert the user using JavaScript that this is an invalid file?

Comment: alert("invalid file type"); ?

Comment: but the file extension .JPG is valid only but the actual content is of type .dll

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript, running in the browser in a standard security context, has no way to determine this.

You have to handle this check server side.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way doing it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There **is** a way of doing it with javascript.

If the browser supports `window.FileReader` and `window.Blob`, which most do, then yes, you can.

```
if ( window.FileReader && window.Blob )
{
    // get your file from wherever...
    // tacky check jpg in the mime type 
    if ( yourFile.type.indexOf("jpeg") )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```